Connecting GNSS receiver and ArcGIS Field Maps
I have a problem with my GNSS receiver and ArcGIS Field Maps by Esri. I´m using Stonex S500 receiver with cube application. In this application receiver working perfect. But if I start Field maps and change provider to my receiver and start my editing layer then always show a error: Connecting to receiver failed. Check that is receiver and bluetooth on. I´m using Samsung Galaxy tablet.

Android, I have had success by using the paid version of Bluetooth GPS Output https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meowsbox.btgps&hl=en_CA&gl=US  with field maps (which unlocks the timeout)

what do you mean?
